# Python switch case allowing optional arguments

Tags: python

I understand that there are no switch cases in python and that a dictionary can be used instead. But what if i want to pass arguments the function zero() but no arguments to one()? I didnt find any question related to this.

```
def zero(number):
    return number == "zero"

def one():
    return "one"

def numbers_to_functions_to_strings(argument):
    switcher = {
        0: zero,
        1: one,
        2: lambda: "two",
    }
    # Get the function from switcher dictionary
    func = switcher.get(argument, lambda: "nothing")
    # Execute the function
    return func()
```

what is the simplest way to implement this without having to separate them into two cases? i think that func() would need to take the (optional) arguments?

Comment: Which argument are you passing in `zero`?

Comment: `lambda` or `functools.partial` would work. Restructure such that all functions in the map at least *accept* the same arguments, even if they don't all *use* them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

```
from functools import partial

def zero(number):
    return number == "zero"

def one():
    return "one"

def numbers_to_functions_to_strings(argument):
    switcher = {
        0: partial(zero, argument),
        1: one,
        2: lambda: "two",
    }

    func = switcher.get(argument, lambda: "nothing")
    return func()
```

Answer (score 7):

If I understood the case correctly, here is an alternative take for doing that without importing anything and also without lambda. You can just navigate to the necessary methods you already have outside the switcher:

```
def fa(num):
    return num * 1.1
def fb(num, option=1):
    return num * 2.2 * option
def f_default(num):
    return num

def switch(case):
    return {
        "a":fa,
        "b":fb,
    }.get(case, f_default)  # you can pass

print switch("a")(10)  # for Python 3 --> print(switchcase("a")(10))
print switch("b")(10, 3)  # for Python 3 --> print(switchcase("b")(10, 3))
```

> print(switchcase("a")(10))
>
> 11.0
>
> print(switchcase("b")(10, 3))
>
> 66.0
>
> print(switchcase("ddd")(10))
>
> 10

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean a fixed argument to the functions you're calling. If that's the case, just wrap the functions in another function that calls it with the relevant argument:

```
switcher = {
    0: lambda: zero("not zero"),
    1: one,
    2: lambda: "two",
}
```

You can use the same approach to pass an optional arument through from the `numbers_to_functions_to_strings` call:

```
def numbers_to_functions_to_strings(argument, opt_arg="placeholder"):
    switcher = {
        0: lambda: zero(opt_arg),
        1: one,
        2: lambda: "two",
    }
```