# I want to make calculator using switch case statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement, calculator

I am able to make calculator using the If and elsif statement but I am unable to make it with the switch case statement. 
I create basic for switch case but I stacked in how to take argument and how to call that.
Please anyone can help me.
Thank you in advance

[Python switch case allowing optional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648887/python-switch-case-allowing-optional-arguments) 
I tried this but not working

```py
def addition(num1,num2):
    num1 += num2
    return num1
def subtraction(num1,num2):
    num1 -= num2
    return num1
def mul(num1,num2):
    num1 *= num2
    return num1
def division(num1,num2):
    num1 /= num2
    return num1

def module(num1,num2):
    num1 %= num2
    return num1

def default(num1,num2):
    return "Incorrect day"

switcher = {
    1: addition,
    2: subtraction,
    3: mul,
    4: division,
    5: module
    }

def switch(operation):
    return switcher.get(operation, default)()

print('''You can perform operation
1. Addition
2. Subtraction
3. Multiplication
4. Division
5. Module ''')

#Take input from user
choice = int(input("Select operation from 1,2,3,4 : "))

print (switch(choice))
```

Comment: the values in your switcher dict (which are functions) take required parameters but you aren't passing any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news for you, if you are still interested in using the switch case in Python.
you can now use `match` with Python 3.10

like this:

```py
    match operation:
        case 'Addition':
            return num1+num2
        case 'Subtraction':
            return num1-num2
        case 'Multiplication':
            return num1*num2
        case 'Division':
            return num1/num2
        case 'Module':
            return num1%num2
```

For more details read [click here to read this python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
# ...

def switch(operation, num1, num2):
    return switcher.get(operation, default)(num1, num2)

# ...
```

Another option is to return a function from `switch` and call it

```
# ...

def switch(operation):
    return switcher.get(operation, default) # <- no () here, i.e. no calling the function

# ...

print(switch(operation)(num1, num2)) # call the returned function here
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get two numbers as input to perform operation on. Try this

```
def addition(num1, num2):
  num1 += num2
  return num1
def subtraction(num1, num2):
  num1 -= num2
  return num1
def mul(num1, num2):
  num1 *= num2
  return num1
def division(num1, num2):
  num1 /= num2
  return num1
def module(num1, num2):
  num1 %= num2
  return num1
def default(num1, num2):
  return "Incorrect day"
switcher = {
    1: addition,
    2: subtraction,
    3: mul,
    4: division,
    5: module
}
def switch(operation, num1, num2):
  return switcher.get(operation, default)(num1, num2)
print('''You can perform operation
1. Addition
2. Subtraction
3. Multiplication
4. Division
5. Module ''')
# Take input from user
choice = int(input("Select operation from 1,2,3,4 : "))
num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
print (switch(choice, num1, num2))
```

Comment: Thank you very much it is perfectly work @Umesh Chaudhary

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def switch(operation):
    return switcher.get(operation, default)

print (switch(choice)(6,2))
```